# Use Specific Directory for Display Item Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, picture-library, display-form

I am trying to create a custom aspx page with a display item form for a photo library in Sharepoint 2010.

This may be a really basic question, but is there any way to specify a root Folder for this form?

-Library

- Folder 1
- Folder 2

I basically just want to have the form display the photo's from Folder 2.  When I add the Display Item Form in SP Designer it always points to the Root.

I can change this in DVWP by changing the URL, is there a similar option with Display Item Form?

Thanks in advance,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way for this, but I got it working by changing the Data Source Details to 'Recursive All' and then adding a filter on Path for the correct directory via query string so now I just add:

```
?Path=/sites/xxx/yyy
```

to the end of the URL to show a specific directory.

If anyone has a simpler way, I am all ears.